# Google marker displays but the title does not

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dart

I'm sure there is an incredibly simple solution to this but I have been looking over it for a while now and could use some advice. I've placed a marker on the map that displays as it should however the title does not appear when the marker is clicked. I've tried moving the marker in to the initialise function but that hasn't helped so far. Here is the code I am using:

```
function initialize() {

      var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.865149400000000000, -4.258004199999959000);
      var mapOptions = {
      center: Latlng,
      zoom: 9,
      panControl: true,
      zoomControl: true,
      scaleControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE



    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
      mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: Latlng,
      draggable:true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: 'Hello World'


    });



  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Any input would be welcome as I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face.

Comment: the title will be used as a simple HTML-tooltip(you will see it when you hover the marker). What you need is an InfoWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some functionality. By adding 'title' property to the marker you don't magically get event listener for marker click. And you need to have some kind of component where to display the marker title - [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) is enough.

Here is a sample code (taken from JavaScript):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "hello"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```